# Find quadruple solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve equation like this

$$(b+c+d)^{2010}=3\times a$$
$$(a+c+d)^{2010}=3\times b$$
$$(a+b+d)^{2010}=3\times c$$
$$(a+b+c)^{2010}=3\times d$$.

Comment: This question was asked and answered very recently.  BTW note that "2010" is a red herring. The solutions would be the same if the exponents were smaller, larger, or different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $a,b,c,d\ge 0$

$$b+c+d=(3a)^{1/2010}$$
$$a+c+d=(3b)^{1/2010}$$
$$a+b+d=(3c)^{1/2010}$$
$$a+b+c=(3d)^{1/2010}$$

Also,
$$b-a=(3a)^{1/2010}-(3b)^{1/2010}$$ has same sign on both sides if and only if $a=b$.

For the same reason, $a=b=c=d$

Hence
$$(3a)^{2010}=3a$$

> That is $$a=b=c=d=0 \quad \text{or} \quad \frac{1}{3}$$