# Find the values of $(a,b,c ,d.)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Find all values of real numbers $a,b,c, d$ satisfying the following condition

$$(b+c+d)^{2010}=3a$$ $$(a+c+d)^{2010}=3b$$ $$(a+b+d)^{2010}=3c$$ $$(a+b+c)^{2010}=3d$$

Comment: @HarshKumar Nice work done to copy the accepted answer from your own question and post it here.

Comment: @Rohan This is my own answer. See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2060060/find-quadruple-solutions

Comment: @HarshKumar Can't believe you just went back and edited that old answer to conceal the plagiarism. I rolled that back for you.